# how to get all radio button value by name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like the title say i want to get all the radio button value that using the same name. here is the html code

```
<input type="radio" id="choice-yes-1" name="choice[0]" value="Yes" /> Yes <br/>
<input type="radio" id="choice-no-1" name="choice[0]" value="No" /> No <br />
<input type="radio" id="choice-yes-2" name="choice[1]" value="Yes" /> Yes <br />
<input type="radio" id="choice-no-2" name="choice[1]" value="No" /> No <br />
```

i want the javascript kinda like this

```
ctr = 0;
for (i=0;i<2;i++){
    if(document.getElementsByName("choice")[i].value == "Yes"){
        ctr++;
    }
}
console.log(ctr);
```

i want some javascript that kinda resulting how many the yes choice.

Comment: Try something like `$('input[value=Yes]:checked').length` it should return the number of elements that is checked and has the value yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('input[id^=choice-][value=Yes]:checked').length` to get all `checked` elements with the value of `Yes`

```js
$('input[id^=choice-][type=radio]').change(function() {
  console.log($('input[id^=choice-][value=Yes]:checked').length)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="choice-yes-1" name="choice[0]" value="Yes" checked /> Yes <br/>
<input type="radio" id="choice-no-1" name="choice[0]" value="No" /> No <br />
<input type="radio" id="choice-yes-2" name="choice[1]" value="Yes" /> Yes <br />
<input type="radio" id="choice-no-2" name="choice[1]" value="No" /> No <br />
```

Comment: that is some very legit simple code of jqurey.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByName("choice")` is empty array, because there is no such elements.

Solution:

```
let result = [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]'), function(e){
  return e.value === 'Yes'
})

console.log(result.length)
```

Comment: This looks more like a comment rather than an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the count will go up and down but not below 0

```js
var count = 0;

$('input').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "Yes") {
    count++
  } else {
    if (count == 0) {
      return;
    }

    count--;
  }
  console.log(count)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" id="choice-yes-1" name="choice[0]" value="Yes" /> Yes
<br/>
<input type="radio" id="choice-no-1" name="choice[0]" value="No" /> No
<br />
<input type="radio" id="choice-yes-2" name="choice[1]" value="Yes" /> Yes
<br />
<input type="radio" id="choice-no-2" name="choice[1]" value="No" /> No
<br />
```